# How to set placeholder in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How to set placeholder for `TextField` in JavaFX? How can I do this w/o JavaScript?

Comment: Related: [Clear prompt text in JavaFX TextField only when user starts typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125563/clear-prompt-text-in-javafx-textfield-only-when-user-starts-typing).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the `promptText` property (see [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#promptTextProperty)).

Answer (score 16):

In JavaFX, you can set like the following:

```
TextField searchInput = new TextField();
searchInput.setId("textField");
searchInput.setPromptText("Search");
```