# How to make a non-editable ComboBox display promptText?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I have JavaFX controls that can be associated with many, potentially conflicting values.

When the control is a `TextField`, I use the `promptText` property to put the string `(Multiple conflicting values)` into the `TextField` and use the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125563/clear-prompt-text-in-javafx-textfield-only-when-user-starts-typing) to ensure the `promptText` remains visible until the user types into the field.  This works great.

Now, I would like to do the same thing with a `ComboBox`, but I have discovered that a `ComboBox` will display `promptText` only if the `editable` property is set to `true`.  This is a problem for me, because I do not want the user to type arbitrary strings into the `ComboBox`.  I want to limit him to a set of predetermined selections.

Is there a way to make `ComboBox` display the `promptText` even if its `editable` property is set to `false`?  Extending `ComboBox` is an acceptable solution in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to work if I set the `ComboBox` editable, and then acquire the editor (a `TextField`) and set it to not-editable.

```
comboBox.setEditable(true)
comboBox.getEditor().setEditable(false)
```

To keep the `promptText` visible until the user changes the `ComboBox`, one must apply the CSS tricks to the interior `TextField`, not the `ComboBox` itself.

#### Unsolved Problems:

- The user cannot type into the `ComboBox`, but it looks like he can: it is styled like he can, and the mouse cursor even assumes the `I`-beam appearance when it is hovering over the editor portion of the `ComboBox`.
- The user **must click on the button** to unroll and see the items.  He can no longer click on the larger target area of a non-editable `ComboBox`.
- I have seen a loss of focus cause such a `ComboBox` to generate a `selectedItem` changed event, and the new value is not the object originally added to `ComboBox.getItems()`, but a string representation of the original object!  It seems that `selectedIndex()` can be used to work around this.
- Last and least: my `ComboBox`'s `StringConverter` started receiving `null`s when previously, it did not.