# How would I create grayed-out text in a JavaFX TextArea that disappears when the user begins adding text?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textarea

This is a feature that I have noticed in many web apps and I would like it to be in a TextArea on my JavaFX app.

The desktop version of [Hemingway](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/) provides a good example:

[image: Before content added]

[image: After content added]

Comment: [promptText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#promptTextProperty) is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [promptText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#promptTextProperty) on the TextArea.

```
 textArea.setPromptText("Type or paste something to get started...");
```

If you want a more sophisticated solution that transfers the PromptText to a label above the TextField, so the prompt text is still visible when the user types, then the 3rd party [Gluon glisten library](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.2.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TextField.html) does that, or [MaterialFX has many text field prompt and label options](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/wiki/Text-Fields).  From your description, though you probably don't need the glisten functionality and the standard `promptText` implementation in JavaFX TextAreas is probably fine for you.

Related:

- [Clear prompt text in JavaFX TextField only when user starts typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125563/clear-prompt-text-in-javafx-textfield-only-when-user-starts-typing)