# JavaFX - How to override Textfield focus event behavior?

Tags: javafx, focus, textfield

The JavaFX Textfield control has the "Prompt Text" property to inform user what have to be digited.

[image]

However, as soon the control received focus the text of that property gets gone. I would like that the Textfield behaviour was like HTML5 control: only dissapear after first caracter was introduced and reappear if all caracters was erased.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Clear prompt text in JavaFX TextField only when user starts typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125563/clear-prompt-text-in-javafx-textfield-only-when-user-starts-typing)

Comment: @anko Unfortunately this topic did not appear in the search I did on the site.Thank you so much for show me the link.

Comment: typing "prompt text" (which is the term you use in the question) in the javafx tag search field  reveals the duplicate as about 10th result - just saying ;)

Comment: @kleopatra The idea behind my question was to make a custom control. That's why I did a question about "focus event override". I looked all the site's suggested questions and none of them gives me the answer. But Anko's link is the starting point. Just replying... Thank you.